# how to show the most viewed, random and recent posts in the home?

Tags: homepage, recent-posts

I would like to make my home page in such a way it shows the most viewed, random and recent posts by thre differents part by limitin the number of posts......give me at least some hints or idea to try it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this before with custom queries and widgets. You have to be tracking all of these stats, of course, but if you are, it's a rather simple matter to build a widget that displays it and drop it in. If you're not using widgets, you can do the same, it will just take a bit more coding on your part, but use the same concept. Without specifics, I don't think I can go much deeper on implementation for most viewed, but I can give you the other two.

To get random posts, you can just do a `get_posts()` query with your `orderby` set to `rand` and everything else set as normal, voilà , random posts.

Same deal for most recent posts, `get_posts()`, set your `order_by` to `post_date` and your order to `DESC`...which is actually the default behavior for `get_posts()`.

Docs: [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: thank yu. I tried the code from yur link but the out put is post titles and its perma link. What should i do to get the thumbnail of the post?.
If yu tell me how to get the post, i could get the thumbnail preview of those posts.

Comment: My link was a codex page...there were lots of code examples and they all centered solely on getting the post. I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I should admit that i am confusing myself and all.Here we go, i used the code from the link which yu specified [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Random_posts) but i got the post tittle alone. I want it to show the posts instead of tittle. Hope this time i dint or least confused yu. BTW thank yu very much for spendin yur valuable time for me.

Comment: Once you get the post object, you can display posts either by initiating a loop and using functions like `the_title()` or by calling the fields directly from the post object, like so, `$post_object->post_title`. `get_posts()` will return an array of post objects, which you can then use however suits you.

Comment: if yu dnt mind, would yu tell me the exact code which is should put in order to get the post instead of tittle???

Comment: Again, there are multiple ways of doing it. I strongly recommend that you start reading through the codex and basic wordpress tutorials, because I really can't help you if you don't understand the fundamentals of PHP and wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a 'sidebar' that is visible only on your home page using:

```
<?php if(is_home()) {
    // Sidebar code here
}
```

Register the sidebar and use the existing widgets to place the required widgets into the new sidebar.

Comment: But i dont want to show them in my side bars.i want it to display in my home page.